# ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.world.wdcapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, kivymd, buildozer

I am getting the following error when i tried building apk with google colab.
ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.world.wdcapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit.

Buildozer Spec requirements:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.2, pillow==8.4.0, Kivy-Garden==0.1.5, requests==2.27.1, urllib3==1.26.9, cachecontrol==0.12.11, cachetools==4.2.4, certifi==2021.10.8, charset-normalizer==2.0.12, docutils==0.18.1, firebase-admin==5.2.0, google-api-core==2.7.2, google-api-python-client==2.46.0, google-auth==2.6.6, google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0, google-cloud-core==2.3.0, google-cloud-firestore==2.4.0, google-cloud-storage==2.0.0, google-crc32c==1.3.0, google-resumable-media==2.3.2, googleapis-common-protos==1.56.0, grpcio==1.44.0, grpcio-status==1.44.0, httplib2==0.20.4, idna==3.3, msgpack==1.0.3, proto-plus==1.20.3, protobuf==3.19.4, pyasn1==0.4.8, pyasn1-modules==0.2.8, pygments==2.12.0, pyparsing==3.0.7, rsa==4.8, six==1.16.0, uritemplate==4.1.1, sdl2_ttf==2.0.15, simplejson, openssl
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might due to the fact that the buildtime environment and runtime environment having different cpu architectures. The quick solution is to try to use a buildtime environment that is similar to runtime. If you have to endure the discrepancy between two environment, you can try to manually install a wheel that works for your runtime environment: https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/#files